# How to apply load more Scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a div in phonegap application and want it to be Load More type infinite loading. 
How to do that?
CSS:

```
#containerReviews ,#container, #containerReviewsPageSummary ,#moreList, #boxofficeList{
    float:left; width:20%; background-color: white; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

[image: scroll load more]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#containerReviews ,#container, #containerReviewsPageSummary ,#moreList, #boxofficeList').scroll(function () {
    if ((this.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() - $(this).height()) <= 100) {
        LoadRefreshedDataPerPage();
    }
});
```